# What does collation mean?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, mysql

What does collation mean in SQL, and what does it do?

Comment: @gbn: Incidentally, collation works in a very similar way in both MSSQL and MySQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[MySQL\]: What is collation method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654077/mysql-what-is-collation-method)

Comment: @Piskvor: Except some of the mySql collation options (e.g., UTF8) aren't available in MSSQL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250.aspx

Comment: @C.B.: Not denying that; the similarity goes deeper than (un)supported charsets.

Answer (score 69):

Collation can be simply thought of as sort order.

In English (and it's strange cousin, American), collation may be a pretty simple matter consisting of ordering by the ASCII code.

Once you get into those strange European languages with all their accents and other features, collation changes. For example, though the different accented forms of `a` may exist at disparate code points, they may all need to be sorted as if they were the same letter.

Comment: Different accents usually mean that they need to be sorted as if they were *different* letters - e.g. `e`,`ë`,`é`,`ě`, and `è` *might* be distinct letters for the purposes of ordering (but possibly the same letter when searching, damn those crazy Europeans ;)).

Comment: @Piskvor: aren't coordinates in your info pointing to a certain country using an alphabet with `42` letters, `15` of them having diacritics?

Comment: @Quassnoi: Well yes, and? Am I implying anywhere that I'm not crazy? ;o) (although thank God for Unicode, I'd be stark raving mad if I still had to work with nation-specific charsets)

Comment: @Piskvor: sorry, sorry, you're perfectly crazy! :)

Comment: Is it only for sort or also for `where st= 'aaa'` ?

Comment: What I found confusing is that you could sort so that the different accented forms of `a` are adjacent, but still treated as separate letters. For example: `aa`, `ac`, `åb`, `åd`, `bc`, `xz` (`a` and `å` are adjacent but treated as separate letters) vs. `aa`, `åb`, `ac`, `åd`, `bc`, `xz` (`a` and `å` treated as same letter).

Answer (score 47):

Besides the "accented letters are sorted differently than unaccented ones" in some Western European languages, you must take into account the *groups* of letters, which sometimes are sorted differently, also.

Traditionally, in Spanish, "ch" was considered a letter in its own right, same with "ll" (both of which represent a single phoneme), so a list would get sorted like this:

- caballo
- cinco
- coche
- charco
- chocolate
- chueco
- dado
- (...)
- lámpara
- luego
- llanta
- lluvia
- madera

Notice all the words starting with single *c* go together, except words starting with *ch* which go **after** them, same with *ll*-starting words which go after all the words starting with a single *l*. This is the ordering you'll see in old dictionaries and encyclopedias, sometimes even today by very conservative organizations.

The Royal Academy of the Language changed this to make it easier for Spanish to be accomodated in the computing world. Nevertheless, *ñ* is still considered a different letter than *n* and goes **after** it, and before *o*. So this is a correctly ordered list:

- Namibia
- número
- ñandú
- ñú
- obra
- ojo

By selecting the correct collation, you get all this done for you, automatically :-)

Comment: OK, so a collation is quite useful for correct sorting, but is it still useful for comparisons? E.g., i'd like to have 'ñandú' and 'nandu' come up as equals, for practical reasons... Could the collation mechanism help me with this task?

Comment: @C.B.: If you mean something like selecting all rows where a column's value equals 'Aéreo' and SQL S. returns rows with 'aereo', 'aereó', 'AerEO' and the like - yes, setting a specific collation for just a query can do that. You'll have performance issues, though, if this collation's very different from the database's native one. And if you use temporary tables, you must also keep track of tempdb's collation... But you do can do it.

Comment: In that case, could you please explain a little bit more? Particularly, would the straightforward query "SELECT word FROM test WHERE word LIKE 'nandu'" be able to do that? And which collation should i use to have it work? (Note that i'm concerned about diacritic marks, and not just accents...)

Comment: @C.B. take a look at the 'AI' or 'AS' part of the collation (Accent Insensitive and Accent Sensitive).

Answer (score 15):

Rules that tell how to compare and sort strings: letters order; whether case matters, whether diacritics matter etc.

For instance, if you want all letters to be different (say, if you store filenames in `UNIX`), you use `UTF8_BIN` collation:

```
SELECT  'A' COLLATE UTF8_BIN = 'a' COLLATE UTF8_BIN

---
0
```

If you want to ignore case and diacritics differences (say, for a search engine), you use `UTF8_GENERAL_CI` collation:

```
SELECT  'A' COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI = 'ä' COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI

---
1
```

As you can see, this collation (comparison rule) considers capital `A` and lowecase `ä` the same letter, ignoring case and diacritic differences.

Comment: just for note: The utf8mb3 character set is deprecated and you should expect it to be removed in a future MySQL release. Please use utf8mb4 instead. **Although utf8 is currently an alias for utf8mb3**, at some point utf8 is expected to become a reference to utf8mb4. To avoid ambiguity about the meaning of utf8, consider specifying utf8mb4 explicitly for character set references instead of utf8. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

Answer (score 11):

Collation defines how you sort and compare string values

For example, it defines how to deal with

- accents (`äàa` etc)
- case (`Aa`)
- the language context:

  - In a French collation, `cote < côte < coté < côté.`
  - In the SQL Server Latin1 default , `cote < coté < côte < côté`
- ASCII sorts (a binary collation)

Answer (score 5):

Collation means assigning some order to the characters in an Alphabet, say, ASCII or Unicode etc.

Suppose you have 3 characters in your alphabet - {A,B,C}. You can define some example collations for it by assigning integral values to the characters

1. Example 1 = {A=1,B=2,C=3}
2. Example 2 = {C=1,B=2,A=3}
3. Example 3 = {B=1,C=2,A=3}

As a matter of fact, you can define n! collations on an Alphabet of size n. Given such an order, different sorting routines likes LSD/MSD string sorts make use of it for sorting strings.

Answer (score 3):

Collation determines how your data is sorted and compared. It's very often important with regards to internazionalization, e.g. how do you sort japanese kanji?

If you google collation and sql server you'll find plenty of articles discussing it!

Answer (score 3):

[Reference is taken from this Article:](http://www.dbrnd.com/2015/10/database-theory-what-is-character-set-and-collation/)
A collation is a set of rules for comparing characters in a character set. It has also ruled for sorting of characters and proper order of two characters varies from language to language.
A Collation compared two strings like, if a word is greater than another one, and sort accordingly.

If you are using “latin1” Character set, you can use “latin1_swedish_ci” Collation.

You have to choose right collation because wrong collation may affect your database performance.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation

> Collation is the assembly of written information into a standard order. (...) A collation algorithm such as the [Unicode collation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_collation_algorithm) defines an order through the process of comparing two given character strings and deciding which should come before the other.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: This article really explains it all.

Comment: @Joe Pineda. Maybe it does really explain it all, but does the reader want to know it all? Or is it possible the reader simply wants a concise, reliable answer that covers the most fundamental and commonly used elements and functions of collation so he/she can read it quickly and resume working on whatever task, assignment or project gave rise to the question to begin with?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I appreciate the irony in this

Answer (score 1):

The collation is how SQL server decides on how to sort and compare text.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175194.aspx).