# creating table with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I've got a few question about phpmyadmin table creating sequence

1. I'm wondering what attribute and index mean in phpmyadmin?
2. What is collation??
   (for example if i want to same numbers, which one should i choose?)
3. Also a question about null checkbox
   if i don't want a field to have null values, checking it will make it required or not checking it?
4. And also what is timestamp in default list box?
5. What is the 'PARTITION definition' at the end of the table creating page?
6. And why is there another collation at the end of the table creating list?

i'll be so thankful if someone answers me

Comment: You should start by that : http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php12p2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers for your questions

1) Indexes are used to find rows with specific column values quickly. Without an index, MySQL must begin with the first row and then read through the entire table to find the relevant rows.[Read More](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

2 ) [what-does-collation-mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538732/what-does-collation-mean)

3) IF a column is null you can send empty value to it without an error.IF it is NULL and you will send empty value to it it will gave an error.

4) [TIMESTAMPS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)

5) [What is the 'PARTITION definition'](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_55_partitioning.html)

Comment: i just don't get it
i wanna create a table but it's just sending this error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BINARY NOT NULL, `userdescription` MEDIUMTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bi' at line 1