# SQL Server displaying query results as odd characters

Tags: sql-server, collation

When I attempt to write data to my SQL Server db from this website:

http://kgd.gov.kz/en/wanted?page=0

The fields display like this:

> ÑƒÐ´Ð¾ÑÑ‚Ð¾Ð²ÐµÑ€ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ Ð»Ð¸Ñ‡Ð½Ð¾ÑÑ‚Ð¸ â„–024806818 Ð¾Ñ‚ 19.01.2010 ÐœÐ® Ð Ðš

My Server's Collation is set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. 
The fields are set to nvarchar(max)

How can I display these characters correctly?  I pull data from another site that appears to be in Russian (I think these are russian characters?) and they display correctly.

I'm on SQL Server 2012.  I have researched this on S/O and the only two threads I found did not offer a valid solution.

Thanks.

Comment: My guess is you are sticking this data into a varchar datatype. You need to use nvarchar to accommodate the extended character set.

Comment: This is outside of sql problem - website pushes strings with uncontrolled and/or unsupported encoding. So you have to prepare your database to store _unicode?_ and to modify your website to make it push ensured encoding all the time like _utf8?_. Right now this is utf8 saved as cp1252 (so SeanLange is right about `varchar` type (which is ascii) usage instead of `nvarchar` for unicode support).

Comment: Answer on "what is a collation" question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538732/what-does-collation-mean It has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: @SeanLange I edited my post to include that my fields are in fact nvarchar(max)

Comment: It's not a problem with SQL Server. You used ASCII text instead of Unicode and tried to read it with a *different* codepage than the one that was used to store it.

Comment: @IvanStarostin ok just to make sure I understand correctly, the collation SQL_Latin1 collation setting of my db has nothing to do with the problem I'm seeing?

Comment: @Stpete111 Unicode data isn't affected by codepages/collations. Either the field isn't Unicode or the Unicode text is converted to ASCII before it's displayed. How did you store the text anyway? What application did you use? Did you try storing UTF8 instead of UTF16 perhaps?

Comment: Ehmmmm, that page shows up OK. Did you hard-code an encoding on the *web page* perhaps?

Comment: No repro on Edge, Chrome, IE11 as long as the encoding is left to its default value. The `charset` meta tag is set to UTF8. Did you switch your **browser's** encoding to Latin1? That's the only way the page will appear with mangled text.

Comment: @spete111 correct. Your problem is about storing and encoding, not sorting/comparing strings.

Comment: @IvanStarostin this isn't about storing. The page displays correctly unless one modifies the encoding from the browser's menu

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That looks to me like a "robustness" made by two mirror bugs. And you described how to make it fail.

Comment: @IvanStarostin no, I just clicked on the link. The page displays without problems, eg: `Wanted person full name: 
КАСКАТАЕВ ТАИР ЕРКИНОВИЧ`. The only way to get garbled text is to actually go to the browser's menu and change the encoding to `Western Europe`. That produces `Wanted person full name: 


ÐšÐÐ¡ÐšÐÐ¢ÐÐ•Ð’ Ð¢ÐÐ˜Ð  Ð•Ð ÐšÐ˜ÐÐžÐ’Ð˜Ð§`. Either the OP changed the browser's encoding without realizing it, or the link isn't the actual page

Comment: @IvanStarostin the actual text seems to be the `Identity Documents` section. `Identity documents: 
Удостворение личности №039344681 от 02.12.2015 вылан МВД РК` with UTF8 appears as `dentity documents: 
Ð£Ð´Ð¾ÑÑ‚Ð²Ð¾Ñ€ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ Ð»Ð¸Ñ‡Ð½Ð¾ÑÑ‚Ð¸ â„–039344681 Ð¾Ñ‚ 02.12.2015 Ð²Ñ‹Ð»Ð°Ð½ ÐœÐ’Ð” Ð Ðš` if encoding is set to Western Europe

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, just as I said: uncontrolled conversion from multibyte string to single-byte at first and uncontrolled displaying and conversion of broken string to _whatever it is_ in the end. It does look like correct behaviour when **you guess** the right encoding.