# what do collation and cardinality mean in mysql index?

Tags: mysql, indexing

When show index in a table, there are two parts Collation and Cardinality which I don't understand what there usage is. Anyone could briefly explain?

Comment: dup of [What is cardinality in MySQL? PLease explain simple non technical language](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2566211/), [What is collation method?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1654077/). See also [Difference between Encoding and collation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7723648/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collation is the way sorting takes place, based on the character set you specify.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html

Cardinality is basically "How many unique elements does this column contain."  A table with low cardinality has few unique values.  Lookup tables generally have much lower cardinality than tables of a particular entity such as Customers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28SQL_statements%29